# How to convert 4d numpy array of images to 3d?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 4d numpy array of shape (80,8,8,3). It's 80 images 8x8, 3 channels. I want to make one large image out of them with 8 rows and 10 columns. How can I convert 4d array to 3d with reshaping to a needed shape? I tried `np.concatenate(images[i:i + 10,:,:,:]` but it doesn't work in some reason.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46589058/reshape-4d-numpy-array-into-3d
I think it's duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshape 4D numpy array into 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46589058/reshape-4d-numpy-array-into-3d)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to see them, you could make a plot without fiddling with your data:

```
data = np.random.random((80, 8, 8, 3))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=8, ncols=10, figsize=(10, 8))
for ax, img in zip(axs.ravel(), data):
    ax.imshow(img)
    ax.axis('off')
```

This results in:

[image: matplotlib output]

If you really want to reshape it, you can do this:

```
n, h, w, c = data.shape
data_new = (data.reshape(8, 10, h, w, c)
                .swapaxes(1,2)
                .reshape(h*8, w*10, c))
```

To plot this result:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
plt.imshow(data_new)
plt.axis('off')
```

[image: matplotlib output]

Comment: Thank you! What's the purpose of .swapaxes(1,2)?

Comment: @IvanSmirnov The reshape is a bit tricky, so first we separate the rows and columns, then shuffle the axes around before the second reshape. Hard to explain...  Try just doing `data.reshape(64, 80, 3)` (without the extra reshape and move axis) you might see what I mean.

Comment: I have a case similar to the question asked. The only difference is that my 4D array has the shape (31824, 20, 20, 3) which I want to convert to (3120, 4080, 3). Could you kindly tell me how to do this?

Comment: @Skywalker Try this: https://gist.github.com/kwinkunks/4f7b1e734386d2cc4c64fc5bf4b8c17b